# RavenDb Map/Reduce Nested Arrays

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to create the equivalent of a group_by/mysql in RavenDb

Json document looks like:

```
{
 "region" : "EUW",
 "players" : [
         {
            "position" : 2,
            "summoner_id" : 123456,
            "game_won": 1
         },
         {
            "position" : 1,
            "summoner_id" : 123459,
            "game_won": 0
         },
         {
            "position" : 3,
            "summoner_id" : 123458,
            "game_won": 1
         },
         {
            "position" : 4,
            "summoner_id" : 123457,
            "game_won": 0
         }
             ]
}
```

Having multiple documents like this, I need to find howmany times summoner_id 123456 has had position 2 or any of the other positions 1-6 and howmany times did he win in that position

The Index needs to be queryable on region and summoner_id

Outcome would look like

```
 {
   "positions" : 
         [
           { "position" : 1,
             "total" : 123,
             "won" : 65
           },
           { "position" : 2,
             "total" : 37,
             "won" : 10
           }
         ]
   }
```

What I currently have

Maps

```
from game in docs.Games
from player in game.Players
select new {
    player.position,
    player.summoner_id,
    game.region,
    PosCounter = 1,
    WonCounter = player.game_won == 1 ? 1 : 0
}
```

Reduce

```
from result in results
group result by result.Position into g
select new {
    g.Key.position,
    g.Key.summoner_id,
    g.Key.region,
    PosCounter = g.Sum(x => x.PosCounter),
    WonCounter = g.Sum(x => x.WonCounter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Property names are case sensitive. You need have:

```
{
 "region" : "EUW",
 "players" : [
         {
```

But uses:

```
from game in docs.Games
from player in game.Players
```

Also, in the metadata of your documents, make sure that you have:

```
"Raven-Entity-Name": "Games"
```